# Key constraints in nested type

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to define constraints in typescript?
How do I define these constraints?

In my example below, `value` and `options` of the `type select` should be one of the keys of form.options and options[].value.

```
type OptionProps = Array<{
    value: string,
    label: string
}>

type SelectProps = {
    value: string // should be keyof form["options"][this["options"]]
    options: string //should be keyof form["options"]
}

type FormProps = {
    selects: SelectProps[],
    options: {
        [id: string]: OptionProps
    }
}


let test: FormProps = {
    options: {
        alpha: [
            {value: "1", label: "first"},
            {value: "2", label: "second"},
            {value: "3", label: "third"}
        ]
    },
    selects:[
        {options: "alpha", value: "1"}, //valid entry
        {options: "alpha", value: "4"}, //invalid entry, there is no 4 in options.alpha
        {options: "beta", value: "4"}, //invalid entry, there is no options.beta
    ]
}
```

Comment: It's hard to comprehend what are you trying to achieve, since you've decided to use camelCase for types and also use the same identifiers for properties.

Comment: I have changed the type names. In a js validation it would be `test.selects.forEach(select => { if(!test.options[select.options]) throw ´${select.options} is missing´; if(!test.options[select.options].some(option => option.value === select.value)) throw ´${select.value} is missing´})`